# I have made a encryption code but I keep getting index errors

Tags: python

I have made a code in a block coding language and i have copied in a python format but it keeps getting index Errors. I am new so it may be me being stupid. This code was written with a phone python app so the formatting may not be correct.

My  code
#encoder key

```
rl = 0 # repeat letter
txt = "aa" #your text goes here
r = 1 # repeat
Alpha =(" ","a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","")
#key end
while rl<(len(txt)):
 rl += 1
 while (r != (Alpha.index(txt[r]))) or (r <=27):
  r += 1
 num1 = (str(Alpha.index(txt[rl])))
 num1 = str(num1)
 en = (en+(str(len(num1))+(str(num1))))
print(en)
```

#I have tried to make it work  and as  I said it keeps saying Indexerror
i was expecting the length of the number then the number of the letter and then add it to its previous self. like  for A it would be 11  or for k it would be 211.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few changes you need to make in your code

1: `en` variable is not defined, you need to define it: empty string, `en=""`

2: Second while a loop is not required, remove it

3: `rl + 1` should be moved at the end of the loop, it should be incremented only when the current iteration is done

---

The updated code should look like below

```
rl = 0 # repeat letter
txt = "aa" # your text goes here
Alpha = (" ", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z")
# key end
en=""
while rl < len(txt):
  num1 = str(Alpha.index(txt[rl]))
  en = en + str(len(num1)) + num1
  rl += 1
print(en)
```

---

Output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your list of characters (except for the first element) are all lowercase and they're in alphabetical order. Therefore you don't need that list because the values can be calculated.

e.g.,

```
txt = 'k' # your text goes here. must be lowercase
en = []
BASE = ord('a') - 1

for c in txt:
    i = ord(c) - BASE
    en.append(f'{1 if i < 10 else 2}{i}')

print(''.join(en))
```

**Output:**

```
211
```